# Reading mbTiles from assets folder in osmdroid

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am new to `osmdroid`. I am developing an application in which i am using offline maps. i want to read `mbtiles` from assets folder instead of `sdcard`. is that possible? if yes please help me .
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK osmroid doesn't support [MBtiles](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/MBTiles) (that is usually only supported by Mapbox toolchain).
But IMHO you can write a custom extension to support MBtiles http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/wiki/HowToIncludeInYourProject

Comment: Wrong, osmdroid does support mbtiles. https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/tree/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/tileprovider/modules